# Custom hash in std::unordered map in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I want to meet some performance requirements in my C++ project. I have found that using `push_back` to an `std::vector` has a performance penalty. Also when I use `find` for the elements of an `std::vector` it also takes more time than using an `unordered_map`.

Is it OK if I use `emplace` on an `unordered_map`? Can the save/get cycle be done faster?

> g++ driver.cpp -std=c++11

The header file is

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_UNOR_MAP_HPP
#define CUSTOM_UNOR_MAP_HPP


#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>


namespace pe
{

    struct pe_hash
    {

        size_t operator()(const std::string& key) const
        {

            std::size_t seed = 0;
            std::locale locale;

            for(auto c : key)
            {
                boost::hash_combine(seed, std::toupper(c, locale));
            }

            return seed;

        }
    };



    struct pe_key_eq
    {

        bool operator()(const std::string& l, const std::string& r) const
        {
            return boost::iequals(l, r);
        }
    };

    using pe_map = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, pe_hash, pe_key_eq>;

}

#endif
```

The driver file (main.cpp) is

```
#include "pemap.hpp"
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>

    inline const std::string& get_map_value(const T& container, const std::string& key)

    {

        if (container.count(key))
        {

            return container.find(key)->second;

        }

        static std::string empty;
        return empty;

    }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    std::string key = "key";
    std::string val = "value1";
    std::string val2 = "value2";

    pe::pe_map container;
    container.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val));
    container.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val2));

    std::cout << get_map_value( container, "key") << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: This really depends on what you are doing.  If you're doing a lot of traversal and occasional lookups `vector` is probably faster.  If you're doing a lot of lookups and no/minimal traversals `unordered_map` might be faster.  If I was you I would try both and profile to know for sure.

Comment: you could use `reserve` and `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` and for finding elements it helps to sort the vector

Comment: _"I have found that using push_back to an std::vector has a performance penalty."_ Why not use `emplace_back()`? After a `reserve()` if possible, as tobi303 said. _"Also when I use find for the elements of an std::vector it also takes more time than using an unordered_map."_ How many elements are you adding, and what is their distribution? Obviously the answer to which container can lookup fastest depends upon that. There's not much question to answer without knowing that info. Also, under which optimisation level are you compiling?

Comment: @NathanOliver so do you think that using the unordered map there is no performance gain?

Comment: How on Earth do you conclude that from Nathan's message? He specifically said that it depends on the elements, and that you need to try and profile yourself, not that there is necessarily no difference. Also, compare after giving `vector` a fair playing field, as tobi303 explained.

Comment: @cateof "so do you think that using the unordered map there is no performance gain?" it could be even slower or could be faster depends on data and usage. If one is always better than another then library creators would not bather to put them both.

Comment: @cateof Depending on what you are doing it could make your code slower.  Just because it has a better algorithmic complexity does not mean it is faster.  For instance bubble sort is faster than quick sort for certain data sets.  This is why profiling is so important.  Get real numbers and then make your changes and see what the new numbers are.  Theory is fine but reality has a way of upsetting theory.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am doing a lot of lookups. I don't want to traverse the container, just what fast "finds".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to meet some performance requirements in my C++ project.

Here are the steps you should do:

- run profiler
- identify which code and data manipulation takes the most time
- think about better algorithm and/or data organization for your case (container type is one of them)
- if performance now is enough, you are done, if not try to optimize code, that takes most time

You would not get a good answer just to look at a container in vanilla example. You need to optimize your program, not example.